# Implement a for loop or do while loop in windows md-dos batch file

Tags: batch-file

My coding for creating users is as follows:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo     SELECT OPTION
echo     -------------
echo.
:menu
echo     1- Create username
echo     2- Create password
echo     3- Delete username
echo     4- Exit
echo.
pause
set /p option=enter option 1 2 3 or 4:
if "%option%"=="1" goto createuser
if "%option%"=="2" goto createpass
if "%option%"=="3" goto deluser
if "%option%"=="4" goto exit

:createuser
echo Enter username
set /p var=Username:
net user %var% /add
echo Username successfully entered
goto exit

:createpass
echo Enter password
set /p var=Username:
net user %var% *
echo Password successfully entered
goto exit

:deluser
echo Enter user to be deleted
set /p var=Username:
net user %var% /del
echo User successfully deleted
goto exit

:exit
```

It successfully runs when tested but would like to know how to successfully implement a for loop to see if user enters any option outside of numbers 1-4 such as an error. Also a for loop for when a user has been successfully added, if they would like to create another user or exit the program.

Comment: Nontrivial tasks in batch... the horror... \*sob\*

Comment: @delnan, those are trivial. It might just look a bit unfamiliar to the uninitiated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After each section, you could change `goto exit` to `goto menu` and add

```
echo Error: Choose 1, 2, 3, or 4
goto menu
```

right before `:createuser`

Answer (score 1):

A for loop consists of these parts:

-A variable for counting the number of loops
-Actual content
-A line that increments the loop counter variable
-An if statement that does a GOTO out of the loop if loop counter has exceeded some value
-A GOTO that goes to the beginning of the loop

Something like

```
set /p count = 0
:loopstart
doStuff
set count = count + 1
if %count%==10 GOTO loopend
GOTO loopstart
```

A while loop is the same thing, except instead of counting a loop counter, you substitute some other conditional such as `if %option%=="quit" GOTO loopend`

Hope you can get what you want based on this info.  Sorry if my syntax isn't perfect, I don't use batch files very often.

Comment: A `for` loop should be done with `for`, though: `for /l %%i in (0,1,10) do (...)`