# Windows batch - Breaking out of a loop using variables

Tags: batch-file

So, I've been trying to create a simple spinning line thing that goes on for a set number of loops. I've encountered a problem: I can't find a way to add to a variable, or have a loop counter. This is my code so far (Other general criticisms are accepted too: I'm new to this and it all helps.)

```
@echo off
:1
echo
echo
echo
echo -
echo
cls
echo
echo
echo /
echo
cls
echo
echo
echo I
echo
cls
echo
echo
echo \
echo
cls
echo
echo
echo -
echo
IF %timer%
goto 1 
pause
```

Really sorry if it's already been asked; I just can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Also, it's very possible this could just be a simple command, in which case i apologise again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement a for loop or do while loop in windows md-dos batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370807/implement-a-for-loop-or-do-while-loop-in-windows-md-dos-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of errors with your code as it stands.

The major one is

```
IF %timer%
goto 1
```

Batch is a ver old-fashioned language and is very particular about syntax. You can get a syntax description by typing

```
if /? |more
```

at the prompt. (replace `if` with the keyword you desire)

`if` requires

```
if string1==string2 thingtodoiftrue
```

Over the years, the syntax has been expanded, still maintaining the old version for compatibility so that the general form is now

```
if string1==string2 (thingtodoiftrue) else (thingtodoiffalse)
```

where `==` may now be a number of operators (equ, neq, ...); you can add a /i switch to make the strings case-insensitive, or a `not` keyword to reverse the sense. The parentheses are optional if the thingtodo is a single statement.

There are some quirky syntax requirements however. Either thingtodoiftrue or `(` must be on the same physical line as the `if` keyword. The sequence `) else (` must all be on one physical line (if it's used)

As for performing some variety of count using your original structure, there are many ways. Here's one:

```
@echo off
set count=15
:1
....
set /a count=count-1
IF %count% neq 0 goto 1 
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for. This runs the code 10000 times and it could be modified according to your need.

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,10000) do (
echo -
cls
echo /
cls
echo I
cls
echo \
cls
)
```

Cheers, G

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Get a 0x13 character (carriage return) char inside a variable    
    for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

    rem Spin the line
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for /l %%a in (1 1 5000) do for %%b in (- \ ^| /) do (
        set /a "pct=%%a / 50"
        <nul set /p ".=%%b !pct!%% !cr!"
    )
    endlocal
```

The basic idea is to output the spinning element, followed by the percentage. To keep all the output in the same line

```
<nul set /p "var=outputtext"
```

is used. This echoes the indicated text to console, waits for input, that is readed from nul, ending the prompt wait and continues without moving the cursor to the next line. There is no line feed

Now, it is necessary overwrite this line with the new information each time. To do it, it is necessary to get a carriage return character into a variable. For it, the `for /f` is used, retrieving the needed carriage return character from the output of the `copy` command.

**note**: the `disabledelayedexpansion` is necessary in this step to avoid problems if the full path/filename of the batch file (`%~f0`) contains any exclamation character.

The remaining code just iterates painting the corresponding character in the list, calculating the percentage to output and printing all to the console, without the line feed (`<nul set /p ...`) but with an aditional carriage return that moves the cursor to the start of the line. So, the next output will overwrite the previous one

**note**: in this case, `enabledelayedexpansion` is needed to get access to the content of the changed percentage variable and to output the carriage return. Without delayed expansion active, the parser removes the carriage return from the output.